# Can I get random damage roll from a function in constructor of a class?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, unity-game-engine

I have a question about using functions in constructor.
I'm creating a simple inventory, which is made of 2 scripts: EquipmentGenerator.cs and CharacterInventory.cs.
The latter acceses also a script for rolling dice.

In short, it's all about this line:

```
Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Longsword", "Most popular type of sword, weapon of choice for many warriors and mercenaries.", false, 15, "gp", 3, "Longsword", "1d8", "slashing", diceRolls.Rolld8(), new List <string>() {"Versatile (1d10)"}));
```

I need to be able to use diceRolls.Rolld8(), which is in Weapon class constructor as c_dmg_roll so that each time I get new result (it's just Random.Range).

EquipmentGenerator consists of classes made this way:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item : IComparable<Item>
{
    public string name, description;
    public bool stackable;
    public int value;
    public string coin_type;
    public int weight;
    //  public string model_path;

    public Item (string c_name, string c_description, bool c_stackable, int c_value, string c_coin_type, int c_weight)
    {
        name = c_name;
        description = c_description;
        stackable = c_stackable;
        value = c_value;
        coin_type = c_coin_type;
        weight = c_weight;
        //  model_path = c_model_path;
        //, string c_model_path)
    }
    public int CompareTo(Item other)
    {
        return String.Compare (name, other.name);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Weapon : Item, IComparable <Weapon>
{
    public string weapon_prof;
    public string dmg_die;
    public string dmg_type;
    public int dmg_roll;
    public List <string> weapon_properties;

    public Weapon (string c_name, string c_description, bool c_stackable, int c_value, string c_coin_type, int c_weight, string c_weapon_prof, string c_dmg_die, string c_dmg_type, int c_dmg_roll, List <string> c_weapon_properties) : base (c_name, c_description, c_stackable, c_value, c_coin_type, c_weight)
    {
        weapon_prof = c_weapon_prof;
        dmg_die = c_dmg_die;
        dmg_type = c_dmg_type;
        dmg_roll = c_dmg_roll;
        weapon_properties = c_weapon_properties;            
    }
    public int CompareTo(Weapon other)
    { return String.Compare (name, other.name);     }
}
```

And this is CharacterInventory:

```
public class CharacterInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Weapon> char_inv_weapon;
    public List<Armor> char_inv_armor;
    public List<Potion> char_inv_potion;
    public List<Item> char_inv_other;

    DiceRolls diceRolls = new DiceRolls();

    void Start () {
        Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Longsword", "Most popular type of sword, weapon of choice for many warriors and mercenaries.", false, 15, "gp", 3, "Longsword", "1d8", "slashing", diceRolls.Rolld8(), new List <string>() {"Versatile (1d10)"}));
        Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Shortsword", "Sharp, lightweight, piercing weapon commonly used by shorter races and rogues.", false, 10, "gp", 2, "Shortsword", "1d6", "piercing", diceRolls.Rolld6(), new List <string>() {"Light", "Finesse"}));
        Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Quarterstaff", "Long, blunt staff, typically made of wood. Common for wanderers, travellers, seen in use by wizards, druids and monks.", false, 2, "sp", 4, "Quarterstaff", "1d6", "blunt", diceRolls.Rolld6(), new List <string>() {"Versatile (1d8)"}));


        // Debug: Count current inventory items and list them in Console via foreach loop

        Debug.Log ("Current number of weapons in character's inventory: " + char_inv_weapon.Count + ". Check all item details in Unity Editor's Inspector on the right. Below see a list of weapons:");
        foreach (Weapon weapon in char_inv_weapon) {
            Debug.Log ("Weapon name and description plus rolled damage:  " + weapon.name + ":  " + weapon.description + " Rolled damage: " + weapon.dmg_roll);
        }

        Debug.Log ("Current number of weapons in character's inventory: " + char_inv_weapon.Count + ". Check all item details in Unity Editor's Inspector on the right. Below see a second roll of list of weapons:");
        foreach (Weapon weapon in char_inv_weapon) {
            Debug.Log ("Weapon  and description plus damage rolled second time:  " + weapon.name + ":  " + weapon.description + " Rolled damage: " + weapon.dmg_roll);
        }

    }

    // Sorting

    public void Add_to_inventory(Item it)
    {
        if (it is Weapon)
        {
            char_inv_weapon.Add((Weapon)it);
            char_inv_weapon.Sort();
        }
        else if (it is Armor)
        {
            char_inv_armor.Add((Armor)it);
            char_inv_armor.Sort();
        }
        else if (it is Potion)
        {
            char_inv_potion.Add((Potion)it);
            char_inv_potion.Sort();
        }
        else
        {
            char_inv_other.Add(it);
            char_inv_other.Sort();
        }
    }
```

Part of the script / class DiceRolls for rolling dice:

```
    // define d8 rolls
   public int Rolld8() {
        d8 = Random.Range (1, 9);
        return d8;
    }
```

All works great except one thing: I can't get a random damage each time I access weapon.dmg_roll. Debug.Log shows the same number every time.
I'm just learning, but couldn't find info how to make it work.
Do you have any ideas how can I fix it?

I could make an "if" that would check if a string dmg_die == "1d8" and then make a roll from function. But is there a way to make that random roll happen without this step? Writing dmg_roll as Random.Range in a parameter of a weapon added to list isn't rolling another number too, even if I put it in Update () and run by Input.GetKeyDown.

Answer (score 1):

> All works great except one thing: I can't get a random damage each
>   time I access weapon.dmg_roll.

Abstract weapon damage into it's own class that will be instantiated once. Call the class in your method call, IWeaponDamageService.Roll(IWeaponType type),  that performs the 'hit' by calling your other object. I honestly think you are looking for command pattern.

http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

edit here:

```
Debug.Log ("Current number of weapons in character's inventory: " + char_inv_weapon.Count + ". Check all item details in Unity Editor's Inspector on the right. Below see a list of weapons:");
var weaponService = new WeaponService();
            foreach (Weapon weapon in char_inv_weapon) {
                Debug.Log ("Weapon name and description plus rolled damage:  " + weapon.name + ":  " + weapon.description + " Rolled damage: " + weaponService.GetDamageRoll(weapon)
            }
public class WeaponService{

public int GetDamageRoll(object wpn){
if(wpn.name == "LongSword"){
return 49;
}
else{
...
}
}
}
```

hth

Edit #3, for D&D!

Here is the code that shows each weapon having its own random. I think DICEROLLS was effed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var diceRolls = new DiceRolls();
            var inventory = new CharacterInventory();

            inventory.Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Longsword",
                "Most popular type of sword, weapon of choice for many warriors and mercenaries.", false, 15, "gp", 3,
                "Longsword", "1d8", "slashing", diceRolls.Rolld8(), new List<string>() { "Versatile (1d10)" }));
            inventory.Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Shortsword",
                "Sharp, lightweight, piercing weapon commonly used by shorter races and rogues.", false, 10, "gp", 2,
                "Shortsword", "1d6", "piercing", diceRolls.Rolld6(), new List<string>() { "Light", "Finesse" }));
            inventory.Add_to_inventory(new Weapon("Quarterstaff",
                "Long, blunt staff, typically made of wood. Common for wanderers, travellers, seen in use by wizards, druids and monks.",
                false, 2, "sp", 4, "Quarterstaff", "1d6", "blunt", diceRolls.Rolld6(),
                new List<string>() { "Versatile (1d8)" }));


            // Debug: Count current inventory items and list them in Console via foreach loop

            Console.WriteLine("Current number of weapons in character's inventory: " + inventory.char_inv_weapon.Count +
                              ". Check all item details in Unity Editor's Inspector on the right. Below see a list of weapons:");
            foreach (Weapon weapon in inventory.char_inv_weapon)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Weapon name and description plus rolled damage:  " + weapon.name + ":  " +
                                  weapon.description + " Rolled damage: " + weapon.dmg_roll);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Current number of weapons in character's inventory: " + inventory.char_inv_weapon.Count +
                              ". Check all item details in Unity Editor's Inspector on the right. Below see a second roll of list of weapons:");
            foreach (Weapon weapon in inventory.char_inv_weapon)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Weapon  and description plus damage rolled second time:  " + weapon.name + ":  " +
                                  weapon.description + " Rolled damage: " + weapon.dmg_roll);
            }
        }
    }



    [System.Serializable]
    public class Item : IComparable<Item>
    {
        public string name, description;
        public bool stackable;
        public int value;
        public string coin_type;
        public int weight;
        //  public string model_path;

        public Item(string c_name, string c_description, bool c_stackable, int c_value, string c_coin_type, int c_weight)
        {
            name = c_name;
            description = c_description;
            stackable = c_stackable;
            value = c_value;
            coin_type = c_coin_type;
            weight = c_weight;
            //  model_path = c_model_path;
            //, string c_model_path)
        }

        public int CompareTo(Item other)
        {
            return String.Compare(name, other.name);
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Weapon : Item, IComparable<Weapon>
    {
        public string weapon_prof;
        public string dmg_die;
        public string dmg_type;
        public int dmg_roll;
        public List<string> weapon_properties;

        public Weapon(string c_name, string c_description, bool c_stackable, int c_value, string c_coin_type,
            int c_weight, string c_weapon_prof, string c_dmg_die, string c_dmg_type, int c_dmg_roll,
            List<string> c_weapon_properties) : base(c_name, c_description, c_stackable, c_value, c_coin_type, c_weight)
        {
            weapon_prof = c_weapon_prof;
            dmg_die = c_dmg_die;
            dmg_type = c_dmg_type;
            dmg_roll = c_dmg_roll;
            weapon_properties = c_weapon_properties;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Weapon other)
        {
            return String.Compare(name, other.name);
        }
    }


    public class CharacterInventory
    {
        public List<Weapon> char_inv_weapon;
        public List<object> char_inv_armor;
        public List<object> char_inv_potion;
        public List<Item> char_inv_other;


        public CharacterInventory()
        {
            char_inv_weapon = new List<Weapon>();
            char_inv_armor = new List<object>();
            char_inv_potion = new List<object>();
            char_inv_other = new List<Item>();
        }

        // Sorting

        public void Add_to_inventory(Item it)
        {
            if (it is Weapon)
            {
                char_inv_weapon.Add((Weapon) it);
                char_inv_weapon.Sort();
            }
            //else if (it is Armor)
            //{
            //    char_inv_armor.Add((Armor) it);
            //    char_inv_armor.Sort();
            //}
            //else if (it is Potion)
            //{
            //    char_inv_potion.Add((Potion) it);
            //    char_inv_potion.Sort();
            //}
            else
            {
                char_inv_other.Add(it);
                char_inv_other.Sort();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class DiceRolls
    {
        public int Rolld8()
        {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            var d8 = rnd1.Next(1, 9);
            return d8;
        }

        public int Rolld6()
        {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            var d6 = rnd1.Next(1, 7);
            return d6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure you are right. But I'm really new to C# coding, I don't understand how to do it my code.
Dice rolls are methods in class DiceRolls. Could you explain by example how should I access "Longsword"s dmg_roll ( diceRolls.Rolld8() ) so it gives me a new roll, not just result of initial one? 
I'm really at loss here, done about 5000 lines of code for this project, but this is new to me.

I think I *should* be able to access it in the same script via Debug.Log somehow. Because who knows, I may need to sometime later.

Comment: I couldn't post code in a reply so I modified the original

Comment: Big thanks for your time and effort, but I know I could do it similar way - for example by getting "1d8" string. So I have weapon with parameters (based on Weapon class constructors) and if its "dmg_die" has string "1d8",I would run Random.Range(1,9). If it's "1d6", I'd run Random.Range(1,7).
But I just thought this would be unefficient? Maybe slower than just accessing "diceRolls.Rolld8()" from a weapon's own parameter. It's already there, the problem is, this parameter doesn't roll a new value when accessed. I can't get idea why that value doesn't change, it's a function.

Comment: You are passing your values in your constructor. Ctor happens only once. You could perhaps try a readonly property to access your ctor value AFTER initialization of your get,set properties. If you change 1d8 to 1d10 for a weapon, you are changing the weapon. Every time you change the damage of a weapon you are affecting the output of that weapon. An issue I see is if my character is bad with Maces, their roll should be affected. If a character is uber with swords, + modifiers.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I get it. Because it's in constructor, this is read only variable, and it's value is generated and stored at runtime. Then I can't change the value of that variable no matter what...
So maybe I'll just use that "if", like you mentioned. Do you think this will slow down the process of rolling damage? I need to check an item on the list for a string, using if or case (there are only 5 options, so 5 ifs). Then run a function based on that case (like in your example with name). Is it degrading performance if I used this in game real-time, on a gameobject?

Comment: Yes, I will add modifiers to an actual damage roll. This is just a base roll.
I just though I could use function stored in consturctor of each weapon, to directly get a random result each time. And seems it doesn't work that way. It runs that function once, then the result stays the same all the time.
But if the cost of "switch case" or "if" - based on string value - isn't going to be a performance hit (there will be lots, maybe 20 modifiers to check...), then that's ok.

Comment: I am building this in console because I am a fan of D&D. WIll have something soon.

Comment: On most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to have identical seed values.

Comment: I've copied your version into Unity3D, just edited so it uses UnityEngine and Monobehaviour, so I could assign it to object and press play.
No luck, I've created Update() function and it's still staying same number every time: http://i.imgur.com/diOTN4H.png
void Update() runs basically the same debug as above, just instead of print. Try making function OnKeyDown and see, it's still not changing.

Comment: *Input.GetKeyDown, sorry.

Comment: Within UnityEngine, your Update behavior should call the service code within a callback. I have coded some Unity but you have to separate it out in your Update to get a new response, or something...

Comment: @NicholasKinney when working with Unity you normally don't use `System.Random`, why are you not using [`UnityEngine.Random.Range(int, int)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) to do `Random.Range(1,9)` and `Random.Range(1,7)`

Comment: Enhancements are always a good thing. Thank you for your input! @ScottChamberlain